# Sendgrid Integration / DNS Setup

Tags: dns, sendgrid

I am having some difficulty setting up my SendGrid account to connect to my DNS on Cloudflare and enable custom domain whitelisting for two domains.

My plan is to deploy emails from my Clickfunnels' Actionetics account. Currently, my integration into Clickfunnels is a success and I was able to receive an automated test e-mail (from my custom domain) to my personal email address. I understand that I should be able to send emails from any e-mail address I need (support@domain.com, hamid@domain.com, info@domain.com) without needing to physically needing to go through any setup process to get these emails up and running.  Initially when I went through the SendGrid setup, I needed to add 3 CNAMES to my Cloudflare DNS. Everything successfully installed without any issues from Cloudflare. After speaking with Support, I was told that I might need to retry the whitelabel wizard with automatic security off. Going through this wizard should give 2 txt's and one MX (mail exchanger) record instead of 3 CNAMES.

> "Automating security allows the system to redirect ISPs to SendGrid to check DNS records that follow strict security protocols and are custom to your account. Due to a character limit on TXT records, we are only able to create a custom SPF (sender policy framework) record for users with up to 11 IP addresses. This will not affect deliverability. You would have to go through the whitelabel process again."

If you have experience in this type of issue, please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3):

This is one method the I recommended.

“white-label the domains again but this time completing it with automatic security turned off. Going through this wizard should give 2 txt's and one MX record instead of 3 CNAMES.”

"Automating security allows the system to redirect ISPs to SendGrid to check DNS records that follow strict security protocols and are custom to your account. 
Due to a character limit on TXT records, we are only able to create a custom SPF record for users with up to 11 IP addresses. This will not affect deliverability. You would have to go through the white-label process again."

Thanks, I hope you can resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your question.

SPF is kind of TXT record, it can help receiver know email comes from right ip address.

Whitelabeled Domains help receiver know email really comes from the right server.

Sendgrid need a subdomain and two well-know subdomain to verify your identity.